# EJB Invocation failed ... javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly

My code was running well on Weblogic, and I don't understand why it does not work in Wildfly 10.

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(LogInterceptor.class)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class ActionPlanDaoImpl implements ActionPlanDao {

    
    /** The em. */
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;


@Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void clearStage() throws DataException {
        
        try {
            final Query query = em
                    .createNamedQuery(StgGpsActionPlan.AP_DELETED_STG_RECORD);
            query.executeUpdate();
            
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception Occured in clearStage method");
            
            throw new DataException(e);
        }
    }
```

I suppode it is configuration issues ...
thx for ur help

Answer (score 0):

problem resolved by defining the container in persistence.xml, adding element:

```
<properties>
    <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="JBoss" />
</properties>
```